# React Context Consumer does not update (but Provider does)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a rather simple App with a few components, of which 2 need to have one-directional state-share. They both are nested quite far apart, so I am trying to use ReactContext.

`React 16.8.23`

THe problem is, while Provider does update the state and Context is changing it, too - the Consumer does not change, at all.

Here are the two components in question:

Provider

```
class VG extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             id:[24]
        };
    }



    onSelect = (_, value) => {
        this.setState(value)
    }


    render() {
        return (
        <ListingContext.Provider value={this.state}>
            <ContainerDimensions>
                { ({ width, height }) => {
                    spec.width = width;
                    spec.height = height;
                    return <Vega spec={spec} onSignalSelectPoint={this.onSelect}/>

                }}
            </ContainerDimensions>
        </ListingContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

And Consumer

```
class Info extends Component {


    render() {  
        return (
            <ListingContext.Consumer>
            {
                selected => (
                <Paper elevation={10} style={{"margin":`20px`, "height":`calc(100% - 64px)`}} >
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                        Here is the listing id: {selected.id[0]}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                        Listing's info
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
                )
            }
            </ListingContext.Consumer>

        )
    }

}

export default Info;
```

Here, the "Info" component stays with the context's default value, no matter what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Info` component does not seem to be under `VG`.

This works:

```js
<MyProvider>
  <MyConsumer />
</MyProvider>
```

This doesn't:

```js
<MyProvider>
  <SomeOtherNode />
</MyProvider>
<MyConsumer />
```